# Rspec controller test for a custom POST method is so confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I couldn't write a post test method for `add_queue_item`

```
      namespace :api do
        namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
          resources :stores do
            post 'add_queue_item' => 'stores#add_queue_item', :as => "add_queue_item"
          end
        end
      end
```

## Exception

```
     2) Api::V1::StoresController POST #create with valid params assigns a newly created api_v1 as @api_v1
         Failure/Error: post :add_queue_item, params: {id:store.id}

         ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
           No route matches {:action=>"add_queue_item", :controller=>"api/v1/stores", :id=>71}
         # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/stores_controller_spec.rb:89:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

## rspec

```
      it "assigns a newly created api_v1 as @api_v1" do
        store = Store.create! valid_attributes
        valid_queue_item[:store_id] = store.id
        # post :create
        # post :add_queue_item
        # post ":add_queue_item"
        post :add_queue_item, params: {id:store.id, queue_item: valid_queue_item}
      end
```

[image: inline]

Comment: Can you try `post: api_v1_store_add_queue_item_path` in your spec

Comment: same exception!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly looks like due to the route being formed needs `store_id`. You should pass `store_id` as params. Details below

---

Your Route formed is

```
api_v1_store_add_queue_item POST   /api/v1/stores/:store_id/add_queue_item(.:format) api/v1/stores#add_queue_item {:format=>"json"}
```

In your case this is the spec (mocked the data)

```
it "assigns a newly created api_v1 as @api_v1" do
  post :add_queue_item, params: {id: 1 , queue_item: { store_id: 3}}
end
```

which gives error

```
    ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"add_queue_item", :controller=>"api/v1/stores", :id=>1, :queue_item=>{:store_id=>3}}
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/stores_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10376 seconds (files took 0.92513 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Passing `store_id` as non nested params

```
it "assigns a newly created api_v1 as @api_v1" do
  post :add_queue_item, params: {id: 1 , store_id: 3}
end
```

**Success**

```
Api::V1::StoresController
"do"
  assigns a newly created api_v1 as @api_v1

Finished in 0.12028 seconds (files took 1.14 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```